# Python code activated with checkbox/button

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I want to call function doit when Checkbutton is ON and stop it when it's OFF.

I tried to do it with button and it kinda works, but when I have my CheckButton in ON and I click my button my window freeze and I can't turn it off again.

```
from tkinter import *
import PIL.ImageGrab
from PIL import ImageGrab
import time
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pyautogui
import random


def doit():
    time.clock()
    while label_text.get()=="ON":
        rgb = PIL.ImageGrab.grab().load()[1857,307]
        print(rgb)
        print(time.clock())
    else:
        print('module is turned OFF')

window = Tk()

label_text = StringVar()
label = Label(window, textvariable=label_text)
label_text.set("OFF")

check=Checkbutton(window,  text=label_text.get(), variable=label_text,
                   onvalue="ON", offvalue="OFF")

label.pack()
check.pack(side="left")

b = Button(window, text="OK", command=doit)
b.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: when you run long-runnign process - your while loop - then mainloop can't works and it can't get mouse/keyboard events from system, sends events to widgets, updates widgets, redraws window. You may have to run long-running process in separated thread. Or you have to run it only once (whithout `while`) and use `after(time, doit)` to do it again. This way mainloop will have time to do its job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run long-runnign process - your while loop - then mainloop can't work and it can't get mouse/keyboard events from system, sends events to widgets, updates widgets, redraws window.

You can run `doit` once - without `while` - and then use `after(time, doit)` to run it after some time. This way `mainloop` will have time to do its job.

```
def doit():
    time.clock()
    if label_text.get() == "ON":
        rgb = PIL.ImageGrab.grab().load()[1857,307]
        print(rgb)
        print(time.clock())
        after(50, doit)
    else:
        print('module is turned OFF')
```

Or use `window.update()` in `while` to give `mainloop` time to update elements.

```
def doit():
    time.clock()
    while label_text.get() == "ON":
        rgb = PIL.ImageGrab.grab().load()[1857,307]
        print(rgb)
        print(time.clock())
        window.update()
    else:
        print('module is turned OFF')
```

If `PIL.ImageGrab.grab()` runs longer then you may have to run it in separated thread.